# Sorting data by specified numbering

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table with data

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME_1 |
| 2 | NAME_1 |
| 3 | NAME_1 |
| 4 | NAME_1 |
| 5 | NAME_1 |
| 6 | NAME_1 |
| 7 | NAME_2 |
| 8 | NAME_2 |
| 9 | NAME_2 |
| 10 | NAME_3 |

I need to sorting the NAME column and set the group number to a given limit number, in that order

| ID | NAME | GROUP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME_1 | 1 |
| 2 | NAME_1 | 1 |
| 3 | NAME_1 | 1 |
| 4 | NAME_1 | 2 |
| 5 | NAME_1 | 2 |
| 6 | NAME_1 | 2 |
| 7 | NAME_2 | 3 |
| 8 | NAME_2 | 3 |
| 9 | NAME_2 | 3 |
| 10 | NAME_3 | 4 |

The specified limit number 3, so that in each group the sorting does not exceed more than 3 group members.
For example NAME_1 = 1 there are 3 participants, because they set only the limit of 3, then there is also NAME_1 = 2, here there are also 3 participants, NAME_2 = 3, etc.

Comment: Which DBMS? Postgres, Oracle, Sql Server, ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Database Oracle

Comment: I setup an example we can work with at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f45c25/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches with your sample data, but is it important that all group_id's correspond with the same name? This won't guarantee that.

Also, with your sample data it's tempting to assume that id will share an ordering with name. But this accounts for that not being the case. If that is true, by all means just use the id instead of row_number().

Rationale - Just integer division with 3 as the divisor, then putter around with the off-by-ones to get the groupings looking right.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f45c25/20

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ID Number,
    Name varchar(10),
    Group_ID Number
); 

INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (1,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (2,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (3,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (4,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (5,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (6,'NAME1');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (7,'NAME2');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (8,'NAME2');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (9,'NAME2');
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,Name) VALUES (10,'NAME3');

select id,
       name,
       ceil(row_number() over ( 
         order by name)/3) as group_id
  from table1 t1
 order
    by name;
```

| ID | NAME | GROUP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME1 | 1 |
| 2 | NAME1 | 1 |
| 3 | NAME1 | 1 |
| 4 | NAME1 | 2 |
| 5 | NAME1 | 2 |
| 6 | NAME1 | 2 |
| 7 | NAME2 | 3 |
| 8 | NAME2 | 3 |
| 9 | NAME2 | 3 |
| 10 | NAME3 | 4 |

Comment: what if the name changes more often then once every 3 records?  Check this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ea82/1

Comment: @BartMcEndree . Totally valid thing to be worried about, that was the word of warning about group id's not necessarily having all the same name in them. Didn't see anything in OP's requirement that would imply that was a constraint, so figured ignoring it with a warning was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax but I think a cursor might be useful for solving this problem.

```
DECLARE  
LastName VARCHAR(10);
     GroupIndex NUMBER;
     NameIndex NUMBER;
     
BEGIN
   LastName := "xxx"
   GroupIndex:=1;
   NameIndex:=0;
   FOR table1_rec IN (
        SELECT *
          FROM table1)
   LOOP
      NameIndex:=NameIndex+1;
      IF NameIndex > 3 OR LastName<>Name THEN
       NameIndex:=1;
       GroupIndex:=GroupIndex+1;
      END IF;
      LastName:=Name;
      Update table1 set Group_ID = GroupIndex WHERE ID=table1_rec.ID;   
   END LOOP;
END;
     
Select * from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing the rules of the group numbering in a MODEL clause will be easier to read than chaining analytic clauses in sub selects (you can remove one of the NAME_1 to see it works in that case too)
:

```
with data (id, name) as (
    select 1, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 2, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 3, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 4, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 5, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 6, 'NAME_1' from dual union all
    select 7, 'NAME_2' from dual union all
    select 8, 'NAME_2' from dual union all
    select 9, 'NAME_2' from dual union all
    select 10, 'NAME_3' from dual -- union all
)
select id, name, grp from (
    select *
    from (
        select id, name, 
            row_number() over( order by id) as rn,
            ceil(row_number() over(partition by name order by id)/3) as rng
        from data
    )
    model
        dimension by (rn)
        measures(
            0 as grp, name as name, rng as rng, id as id
            )
        rules (
            grp[rn] = case 
                when name[cv()-1] is null 
                then 1 else 
                    case when name[cv()-1] = name[cv()] 
                    then 
                        case when rng[cv()] = rng[cv()-1]
                        then
                            grp[cv()-1] 
                        else
                            grp[cv()-1] + 1
                        end
                    else grp[cv()-1] + 1 
                    end
                end
        )
)   
;

1   NAME_1  1
2   NAME_1  1
3   NAME_1  1
4   NAME_1  2
5   NAME_1  2
6   NAME_1  2
7   NAME_2  3
8   NAME_2  3
9   NAME_2  3
10  NAME_3  4
```